# VirtualBox でゲストOS (Ubuntu) インストール時に画面がすべて表示されずボタンが押せない

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Windows10環境なので、VirtualBoxをインストールしてUbuntuをインストールするところでつまづいております。
キーボード設定の画面が途中までしか表示されず、設定ボタンを押すことができません。
同じ問題を解決された方がいらっしゃれば教えていただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: Ubuntuのインストールの手順の詳細を教えてください。isoを利用していますか？どのisoを利用していますか？途中までの画面のメッセージ等は何が表示されていますか？

Comment: ダイアログウィンドウを移動するには, Alt+F7 で行えます (その後キーボードかマウスで)。[参考](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295191/use-alt-f7-to-move-a-window-quickly)

Comment: keitaro_so さんのコメントに追加して、もし可能であればスクリーンショットが質問文中にあると答えやすいです。

Answer (score 2):

Windows キーを押しながら Ubuntu のインストーラ画面をマウスでドラッグしてみてください。

[Ubuntuやフレーバーインストール時、インストーラーの画面がディスプレイからはみ出す場合は](https://kledgeb.blogspot.com/2018/04/ubuntu-1804-96-ubuntu.html)

もしくは ISO イメージからの起動直後にブートパラメータで画面解像度を変更する方法もあるようです。

[Ubuntuでインストール画面がまともに表示されなかったら](https://knowledge4linux.blogspot.com/2015/07/ubuntu.html)

> 4. 起動オプションにフレームバッファの解像度を追記します。
>    　※1番最後の ”--" の後に追記します。
>    　※今回は1024x768の解像度にしたかったので、”vga=791"と指定しています。